# GAE: Best practice for dynamically generated projects

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Let's say I am creating a python-based CMS on GAE (similar to Squarespace/Shopify) which allows users to create a website.

The platform will (automatically?) create a subdomain for each new user and duplicates the application.

Now there are two options:

1) **Create a new Database for the new user**, WITHIN the master GAE project. (I'm worried that if one user gets a lot of traffic it might slow down ALL websites.)

2) **Duplicate the entire project.** (This method seems difficult to accomplish because either I have to manually create an instance of the application for each user, or I have to figure out how to hijack **gcloud.py** (or **appcfg.py**) somehow and store my login credentials in the code.)

Which choice will most likely provide the most performance for the price? Is choice 2 allowed by Google (or even possible)?

**Edit:**
I've done some more research about this, and it's not documented very much. I found this in the docs https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/scripting-gcloud which talks about running **gcloud** from scripts, although I don't think that means from python. I am looking into **appengine-jenkins** to see if it will work for my purpose. Let me know if you have any additional information about this.

Also, it seems like **gcloud** is adding a **create** command within the **projects** command which might be useful for me if I can figure out how to run **gcloud** from my script. https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/projects/create

Comment: The choice 2 could be seen as a violation of the terms of use agreement (as each app has its own free daily quota). https://cloud.google.com/terms/?csw=1: "Restrictions. Customer will not ... create multiple Applications, Accounts, or Projects to simulate or act as a single Application, Account, or Project (respectively) or otherwise access the Services in a manner intended to avoid incurring Fees"

Comment: Yeah I suppose something like this could possibly fall under that. Thanks for finding this. Although if I were to manually duplicate the application for each user, I don't think that would be against this clause.